# How to have Side-By-Side Divs with one taking remaining space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is I would like a set of side by side divs.  These divs can grow to an arbitrary height so vertical aligning is important.  As suggested by another SO post, in order to tackle the vertical align problem I have a structure similar to this.  Please help me fill in the blanks.

```
<div id="main-container">
   <div class="formatter">
       <div class="content1">
              <!--- I am fixed at 200px ---->            
       </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="formatter">
       <div class="content2">
              <!--- I have a rendered element.  I don't know exactly how high or wide I am, but I'm not going to take up the whole thing. --->
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="formatter">
       <div class="content3">
              <!--- I have some text and just want to take up the rest of the main container less padding and borders ----->
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Display within the browser:

[image: Table display]

CSS:

```
#main-container {
     width: 900px;
}

.formatter {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
}

.content1 { 
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I think I must have missed the part of your question where you told us what the question is...

Comment: No problem, but it's hard to help when we don't know what the problem is. Oh, and, y'know, if you don't want the front-end work I could take a look for you, my consulting rates are reasonably competitive... ;)

Comment: Maybe try to find some two column layouts. (I'm sure that you can find more these than an exact answer to your question.) Then you make a two column layout, where the left column is with fixed width and right one takes the rest of the space. If you get this to work, then maybe you can do the same again - only this time you make the same thing happen inside the left column. So you have:

`| fixed       |          content...            |`

And after that

`|fixed |  ... |         content...             |`

This might work, depending on what kind of solution you'll find.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare them as `table-cell`.

Comment: Thanks, but is there another way? (table cells are ugly, it's nested tables).  I was fiddling around with it and let's say I want the middle column to take up the rest of the sapce, the first fixed, and the third variable then table cell won't work.

Comment: I know from twitter bootstrap there is a solution for it. Check the example templates e.g. the admin / backend example.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try an unorthodox approach

Auto width and vertical alignment becomes very easy using CSS **flex** display

Code to get your basic layout, vertical and horizontal alignment (withour padding or borders or text-alignment)

```
<div id="main-container">
       <div class="content1">a
              <!--- I am fixed at 200px ---->            
       </div> 
       <div class="content2">bbb
              <!--- I have a rendered element.  I don't know exactly how high or wide I am, but I'm not going to take up the whole thing. --->
       </div>
       <div class="content3">c
              <!--- I have some text and just want to take up the rest of the main container less padding and borders ----->
       </div>
</div>


#main-container {
     width: 900px;
    display: flex;
}

.content3 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.content1 { 
     width: 200px;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n3CwB/

Now you may want to retain your original HTML structure if you want more control of the alignment of the content (like vertically align middle the content), but this should get you started with the basic layout.